# Build retrofit AAR from Retrofit GitHub repo

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to build the retrofit AAR files from the official repo:

https://github.com/square/retrofit

I have loaded the source code (project) into Android Studio, build the project and everything went fine, all green, but there is no output DIR with any AAR file for retrofit, for it's adapters, converters.

Where is the output for the build ? AAr files ?

Here is the image of a succ build:

[image]

- Update
  When I run assembeDebug there is also not an output dir, here is the screenshoot:

[image]

Comment: When you assembleDebug/Release, output will be generated inside build folder. Building project won't generate aar/apk packages for you.

Comment: @JeelVankhede I have tried running assembleDebug , it has the same output as in the screenshoot and no output DIR anywhere.

Comment: Change Project window to 'Project' from 'Android' and go to build dir and find outputs folder there.

Comment: @JeelVankhede There is no build DIR there also. I will update the question with that screenshoot now.

Comment: @AdrianIvasku how did you solve it? How did you create .aar of retrofit library?